# Displaying variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, document.write

I am trying to create a simple page that takes a user inputted variable, and adds it to a pre set variable.  Then, I would like it to display the answer at the bottom of the page.  The only command I can find is document.write, and that makes a whole blank page besides the answer.  Can you please help me find an alternative command to the document.write?  Here is the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var y = 0;
var z = 10;
var x = z;
</script>
<p>
Add Numbers:
</p>
<input type="text" name="inpt1" id="usap1"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="add()"/>
<script>
function add() {
var z = 9
var y = document.getElementById('usap1').value
var x = z;
var z = ( Number(x) + Number(y) );
document.write(z)
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) wipes out all the existing code from the page and opens a new document. Setting [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) would be the nearest "safe" method.

Comment: create an empty p element and use $("whateverhere").text(valuegoeshere)

Comment: or non jQ `document.getElementById("your-id").innerHtml = z;`

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var y = 0;
var z = 10;
var x = z;
</script>
<p>
Add Numbers:
</p>
<input type="text" name="inpt1" id="usap1"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="add()"/>
<script>
function add() {
var z = 9
var y = document.getElementById('usap1').value
var x = z;
var z = ( Number(x) + Number(y) );
document.getElementById('theEnd').innerHTML= z;
}
</script>
  <span id="theEnd"></span>
</body>
```